# oracle apex 18.2 chart conditional formatting

Tags: oracle-apex

As i am totally newbie to oracle apex technologies i am developing a simple chart application in which I have build a simple Bar Chart in apex 18.2, i want to do some conditional changes on chart on the basis of data retrieving from database , i didn't found any HTML expression box to enter custom HTML Expression , I need some Suggestion or Some good examples for to Customize the Chart behavior via css or java script , i have done googling but didn't found any useful material for apex 18.2 as all of examples are for some older versions.

Comment: What sort of conditional changes do you mean? There are a wealth of customisation examples here https://apex.oracle.com/charts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Charts in APEX 18.2 are based on Oracle JET engine. If you're going spend more time on charts development, I advice you to check out this toolkit, and how it works. (https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/globalGetStarted.html)

If you just need a quick suggestions how to customize chart behavior then:
-set a static ID for your chart in application builder. It should be static ID of whole chart region, not just particular series. 
-in the application use developer tools to figure out how chart widget works. In console you can easly catch the widget by jQuery selector $("#yourStaticID_jet"). "_jet" is crucial here. On this jQuery object you can use method ojChart() to interact with chart widget.

All available options for ojChart method are documented here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E87657_01/jet/reference-jet/oj.ojChart.html

At the beginning you can try:

```
$("#yourStaticID_jet").ojChart("option");
```

what should return object with all current options of the widget. Many of them let you impact the way your chart works. Some of them are not possible to set from application builder.

When you decide to change something dynamicly you can create Dynamic Action (for e.g. on some button) and choose type of action "Execute JavaScript Code". A nice example would be turning on stack property of your chart:

```
 $("#yourStaticID_jet").ojChart({stack: 'on'});
```

There is also way to initialize your chart with some options. For this purpose go to Attribute section of your chart, and scroll down to "Advanced" JavaScript Initialization Code. Help text for this section will provide you example code.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer , I think i was looking for exactly what you posted Thanks